# How to adjust control to fit to the screen inside a listbox?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, wrappanel, listboxitems, listbox-control

I am trying to create listbox with images wrapped in a wrappanel. I want to show the items fit to screen. like if the items width is less than the available screen width then the items should be stretched and if the items width is greater than the available screen width then the items should jump to next row and empty space should be filled.

Code:

```xml
    <ListBox x:Name="lst" Grid.Row="3"   HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto" ite ItemWidth="Auto" ItemHeight="Auto"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <Border BorderThickness="2" Width="Auto" Margin="5,5,5,5" Height="Auto"  BorderBrush="Cornsilk">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="150" Width="150">

                <Image Source="Images/image-s.png" Height="120" Width="120" ></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="Item" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

        </Border>

        <Border BorderThickness="2"  Margin="5,5,5,5" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  BorderBrush="Cornsilk">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="150" Width="150">

                <Image Source="Images/image-s.png" Height="120" Width="120" ></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="Item" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <Border BorderThickness="2"  Margin="5,5,5,5" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  BorderBrush="Cornsilk">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="150" Width="150">

                <Image Source="Images/image-s.png" Height="120" Width="120" ></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="Item" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <Border BorderThickness="2"  Margin="5,5,5,5"  Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  BorderBrush="Cornsilk">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="150" Width="150">

                <Image Source="Images/image-s.png" Height="120" Width="120" ></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="Item" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following container style to your `ListBox`:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MyClass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myContainerStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myContainerStyle}">

    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

(Eventually you have to use `PhoneApplicationPage` instead of `UserControl`)

**UPDATE:** Removed `HorizontalAlignment` as proposed by Jared Bienz

Comment: Technically you only need the following:

<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>    
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">        
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>